# Flutter responsiveness

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to make an responsive app, I launched my app on iPhone 11 and it looks good, but when I want to run it on iPhone 8(smaller devices) it doesn't adapt to screen sizes. I am using `responsive_wrapper` package to achieve it. But it doesn't work.

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdJof.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ResponsiveWrapper.builder` in `SingleChildScrollView`: [see official Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)

But you must do the Container adaptive, not const height. Set the height:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4; // 40% of screen height
```